# Check last commit date of multiple projects in single repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using svn in a single repository structure with multiple projects.

How can i "bulk check" when a commit was last made to each project?

Browsing the repository to check the date for each folder could be a last resort, if reliable.

I thought of browsing it via TortoiseSVN, but still need to know if the date it displays is the actual last date of any commit in any subdirectories, or only when a when a change was last made to the current directory.

Our structure is something like this:

```
Root
 - Customer
   - Solutionname
     - trunk
     - tags
     - branches
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If "project" == "Solutionname"

`svn log URL/TO/Solutionname -l 1 -q` will output short log message for latest commit into Solutionname or any of it's subdir

```
>svn log -q -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | lazybadger | 2013-11-28 02:35:01 +0600 (Чт, 28 ноя 2013)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

log for repo-root, linked to my WC, r4 was committed into /trunk, you can get gawk-ed %5,%6,%7 variables (2013-11-28 02:35:01 +0600) for default FS, or just %3 (2013-11-28 02:35:01 +0600 (Чт, 28 ноя 2013)) for FS=|

or, with `log ... --xml` parse XML output and extract `<date></date>` element

```
>svn log -q -l 1 --xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="4">
<author>lazybadger</author>
<date>2013-11-27T20:35:01.008304Z</date>
</logentry>
</log>
```